# From Netbeans to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Can I easily port Java code from Netbeans to Eclipse and back? I've tried copying over my folder from Netbeans to Eclipse, and it seems to work, but am I likely to run into errors as the project grows?

Comment: Have you tried jar-ing your project and then installing the jar into the other IDE? They often have utilities for de-jar-ing the jar file. This won't help with the classpath issues for any resources not included within the project though.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted - it's helped me - so +1 back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just happen to copy Java source code files and other files like web pages (JSP), resources (JS, CSS, images, properties files, etc), then no, there won't be any problems nor errors.

The problems start when you try to copy all the project structure from Netbeans to Eclipse or viceversa, like .metadata folder or .project file proper from Eclipse. Since there are IDE specific files and folders. Note that these must not be copied from one to another.